# Use Menu to load file from a

Tags: r, menu

I would like to set up a menu based function that will give a user a list of files found in a directory, ask them which one they want to load, and than load that file as a new object.

As far as what the code might look like, here is my best attempt to give you an idea what I'm looking for:

```
#Step 1: First create list of files arranged by date created

F<-file.info(list.files("./myfiles",pattern=".csv",full.names=TRUE))

#Order files according to date created, most recent first
F<-F[with(F, order(as.POSIXct(mtime))), ]

Files<-rownames(F)

#Step 2: Offer menu to user
Choose<-menu(Files,title="Choose which File to Load")


#Step 3: Use result of menu to load file

New_File<-read.csv(*result from menu*)
```

Obviously a few issues with my imaginary code above:

1- I need to use full.names=TRUE in order to use file.info on a sub-folder within my working directory. This works fine, but when I end up using the row names for the menu command- the menu list gets messy. If I am working from a series of sub folders in the working directory, the entire string gets printed as opposed to just the file name (the file name alone would be ideal).

2- I think as I have the ordering set up, the most recent files are last on the list (I would like them first)

3- And lastly, and most importantly, I have no idea to use the result from the menu selection to then load the .csv files into a new R object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work as you wish:

```
select.read.csv <- function(dir) {

   basenames  <- list.files(dir, pattern=".csv")
   full.paths <- file.path(dir, basenames)
   new.order  <- order(as.POSIXct(file.info(full.paths)$mtime), decreasing = TRUE)
   basenames  <- basenames[new.order]
   full.paths <- full.paths[new.order]
   selected   <- full.paths[menu(basenames,title = "Choose which File to Load")]

   read.csv(file = selected)
}

select.read.csv(dir = "./myfiles")
```

Comment: Clever, thanks.  You have a typo - a space in the middle of basenames in the second last line of the function.  It won't let me fix it as edits have to be 10 characters, however.

Comment: Brilliant! Just what I needed

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want, this is already done for you in the tcltk package.  So unless you are doing this as an exercise you will find it easier to just use:

```
library(tcltk)
?tk_choose.files()
read.csv(tk_choose.files())
```

Comment: You might consider adding some explanation